# Design Pattern with Message Dispatcher, Subscriber and publisher

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, command

I recently saw a new pattern (new to me) in an open source ASP.NET MVC 5 project that hase many Command, CommandHandler, and CommandInvoker ,MessageDispatcher, AddSubscriber,PublishEvent -with many  interfaces- and I can't understand the pattern! Can you tell me what is this pattern's name and where can I learn about it? And what is its benefits please? Thanks in advance.
I'm talking about this project:https://github.com/edumentab/cqrs-starter-kit

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is called [Command Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

You can find a good article explaining it in [Martin Fowler's Blog](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html).

Comment: Thanks nvoight for your reply. 
Yes it is CQRS, I mean inside the solution there are multiple EventHandlers , CommandHandlers, Event and Command Subscriber. Are these are also part of CQRS or it is some different design pattern. I am not sure but I can guess it may be a Observer pattern as it is having multiple subscribers  and Publishers

Answer (score 0):

This pattern called CQRS (Command Query Responsibility Segregation).

Benefits of this pattern in the separation of **read** and **write** operations in your application. On the **write side** you focus the business logic of the application, and on the **read side** you provide a convenient model for display data. Events are not a mandatory part of the CQRS, but it can be a good addition to control various parts of the application.

More about CQRS [there](https://cqrs.wordpress.com).